# Maxmind geoipupdate mmdb.gz is not a valid gzip file

Tags: geoip, maxmind

I'am try to update my GeoIP Databases using the geoipupdater.

Using the following ProductIds

```
ProductIds GeoIP2-City GeoIP2-Connection-Type GeoIP2-Country GeoIP2-ISP
```

Geoipupdate Version 2.3.1 is installed

```
geoipupdate -V
geoipupdate 2.3.1
```

When I run the geoipupdate the `City` and `Country` Databases are getting updated/downloaded. But for the `ISP` and `Connection-Type` Updates I got the following output from the updater.

```
url: https://updates.maxmind.com/app/update_secure?db_md5=00000000000000000000000000000000&challenge_md5=0926a7ab0bf38eafe43622a25fd6e7e2&user_id=*****&edition_id=GeoIP2-Connection-Type
/usr/share/GeoIP/GeoIP2-Connection-Type.mmdb.gz is not a valid gzip file

url: https://updates.maxmind.com/app/update_secure?db_md5=00000000000000000000000000000000&challenge_md5=0926a7ab0bf38eafe43622a25fd6e7e2&user_id=*****&edition_id=GeoIP2-ISP
/usr/share/GeoIP/GeoIP2-ISP.mmdb.gz is not a valid gzip file
```

Why are the downloaded `.gz` files aren't valid?

thanks in advance!

Comment: I'd suggest that you contact support@maxmind.com

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error, but the reason was an expired subscription.

```
/my_path/data/GeoIP2-City.mmdb.gz is not a valid gzip file
```

I'd suggest you call the URL generated by `geoipupdate` to see the "real error".

```
curl -i "https://updates.maxmind.com/app/update_secure?db_md5=00000000000000000000000000000000&challenge_md5=f2d60fa3afdaa26b18dd94457a999999&user_id=******&edition_id=GeoIP2-City"

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 21 Feb 2017 08:38:13 GMT
Content-Length: 59
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8

Invalid product ID or subscription expired for GeoIP2-City
```